# Cors not allowed to completed the request in Spring MVC

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-mvc, cors

I am using spring MVC and want to send request from React.js but CORS problem. how i can enable it in spring mvc using ApplicationContext.xml?

i have added this these lines in applicationcontext.xml file but failed to build and run the application

```xml
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
</mvc:cors>
```

i want to allow the react.js send request and cors is working properly in spring mvc when i build the             file it give error can not build.where  i am doing wrong i want to solve it using xml file not by java class

Answer (score 0):

**Configure this in ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="corsFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration">
                <property name="allowedOrigins" value="http://localhost:8081" />
                <property name="allowedMethods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
                <property name="allowedHeaders" value="*" />
                <property name="allowCredentials" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Register CorsFilter bean with the servlet context -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" name="dispatcherServlet">
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </bean>
```

replace http://localhost:8081 fro where your client application is making requests.

Comment: after adding these into my applicationcontext.xml and run the application its give error here is log file 24-Mar-2024 09:30:17.402 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
24-Mar-2024 09:30:17.459 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root

Comment: ClassPath i have library like   cors-filter-2.8.jar & jackson-mapper-asl.jar & jackson-core-asl.jar

Comment: To solve this, you need to ensure that your Spring MVC application has a class that implements the WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: means jar file ?

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score -1):

Add this is package com.your_packge_name and replace MyAppConfig with actual name

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null; 
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MyAppConfig.class}; 
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"}; 
    }
}
```

Comment: if i use the same name MyAppConfig will there be no issue or should i replace with some  my one and one another thing i am using spring-web 4.0 - Will this support cors or not?

Comment: One another question in above class and cofiguration we have done applicationcontext.xml where is there connection between these two ? where we tell that this class take something from context.xml?